# issue with spinner width

Tags: android, spinner

I created a spinner and in my layout file, I set its width to `wrap_content`. In my spinner list, I have items that are as short as 1 character but as long as 15 characters. However, the spinner always has the width of 15 character even if the item is not as long. Therefore, when the item with length 1 is selected, the gap between the text and the arrow is pretty huge and looks bad. I don't know if it makes a difference but my `setDropDownViewResource` is `simple_spinner_dropdown_item`. I'm setting the adapter through the following code:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item) {

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            ((TextView) v).setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(
                    R.color.pick_up_button_background));
            return v;

        }
    };
```

Also, this issue is only present in Ice Cream Sandwich phones. When I used the app on my gingerbread, it worked fine and the spinner is given the width of whichever item is selected. How can I correct this issue??

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Hope this may help you

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerName;         adpt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinnerName.setAdapter(adpt);
spinnerName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
        spnVehicleType.getSelectedItemPosition();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }
});
```

Comment: `ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner` gives me an error as spinnerName needs to be an int